# Angularjs - dynamic template URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive which I would like to be able to load a different template on some logic.

In the example below, the 'type' is a variable on the scope which I would like to pass to the directive to build the URL for the directive's template.

```
<direct type="{{type}}"></direct>

var direct = function () {
  return {
  restrict: 'E',
  templateUrl: function(tElement, tAttrs) {
    console.log(type);
    return 'resources/' + tAttrs.type + '.html';
  }
 };
};
```

The type is not being evaluated but instead the actual string 'type' is being passed in the tAttrs. Do you know what I might be missing out?

Comment: Look into isolate scope, also you can use ng-switch to flip between various directives depending on some value perhaps this is enough then in some custom directives you can write your particular templates you want to load.

Comment: I'm not sure if this was ever fixed.. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1039 might have to take a different approach

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this via isolated scope on your direct directive.

I have made an example for you here: http://jsbin.com/lagez/1/edit

You can see in the example link, that you have to specify attributes that you would like to read inside your directive scope inside the scope: { attributeName: '@' }

The attribute name syntax inside scope: {} should be camel case with first letter small. e.g. typeName, and you specify the attribute-name inside the directive like

Comment: The only problem is that I would like to put the template html in a different file and load the specific file according the the type. Something on the line of: `templateURL: function(tElement, tAttrs) {return type + '.html';}` but I am not able to get to the type param.

Comment: if your type value is pre-determined then you can register this on a ParentController or put data model on a server and then use dependency injection to get the parameter. This way you can connect to a template maybe, but I don't know your context so it's just a hint from me, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're running into is that when templateUrl is evaluated, there's no scope to bind that value to, so it returns the actual string content of the attribute--rather than the interpolated value you expect.